# Jquery open document file on click or it open on browser new tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to open document file on click in browser's new Tab or in its relevant Software, like .doc file open in Microsoft Word.

check my screen shots

[image: Image1]

and

[image: Image2]

Here is my code:

```
var doc1 = obj[i].resume;
var doc = "documents/"+ doc1;   //documents/BPO INTRVW QUE.rtf
html1 += "<td>" + '<a href='+doc+'>'+doc1+'</a>'+ "</td>";
```

Comment: Can you try with `href="'+doc+'"`? Not sure that this will solve your problem though.

Comment: i did not get any idea please provide complete code

Comment: @AamirMansuri , it should be `href="link"`. So, your code must be `href="' + doc + '">...`. Your corrent code breaks html as it outputs `href=doc link` (no quotes).

Comment: @Dharman thanks i clear my issue.

Comment: @Yousof K. thanks your idea very solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  instead of  '

passing string as a href in link like '" "' it should close issue